# Swift Changing font programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am currently setting up views below:

```
func setupViews() {

    self.numberLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero) 
    self.addSubview(self.numberLabel)
    self.numberLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }


    self.numberLabel.textAlignment = .center
    self.numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    self.numberLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.numberLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

}
```

I would like to change the font of the text inside the label to bold font, however it's difficult to see an easy way to do so, following the syntax principles above.

Comment: Why don't you just do `self.numberLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 12)` substituting whatever font you actually want to use.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that I wanted the text to be BOLD, I have edited the initial message as per the requirements I need. Thanks for your Swift reply though.

Comment: Then just use `UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set the font property of the label, for example:

```
numberLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: 200)
```

I'm amazed there's nothing on SO already on this.

Take a look at the reference docs too: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel

By the way, unless you are operating within a closure, or other contexts where the semantics are ambiguous (e.g. in an initialiser) you don't generally need to use self. prefix.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

**For `Swift 5+` and upto latest version `(Swift 5.4)`** period

> ****Stylizing the Font (SystemFont)****

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .medium)
```

where you can set `.weight` provides various `UIFont.Weight` properties as given below

- `.black`
- `.bold`
- `.heavy`
- `.light`
- `.medium`
- `.regular`
- `.semibold`
- `.thin`   (Looks very cool and I guess Apple also uses this somewhere)
- `.ultralight`

**Note that it's only for default `SystemFont` only.
[AppleDocumentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619027-systemfont)**

> ***Changing the Font***

```
UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 16.0)
```

- where name includes the `FontName`
- you can also specify `.weight` by writing `-` before weight **(If that font supports that weight as Not all `fontFamily` supports all
  types of `UIFont.Weight`)**
- **This is more preferable method to use for stylising the font if
  you're not using default `SystemFont`**

Answer (score 1):

If your just using the system font you can also do

```
UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
```

Selecting whichever size you need

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619039-boldsystemfont) on it